# Count cURL requests coming from a user

Tags: php, curl

I have a website that sends out curl requests to other places, it also has a login system. Is there anyway to log how many curl requests are being sent from one user account?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code you have for the cURL requests and the logging system. In the code to make the cURL request, add the logging.

Comment: Create a column in the user table called `curl_requests`. Every time you make a cURL-request, you increment this value by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Create a count function and execute it every time the user does a cURL request:

```
<?php

function count() {

    $currentAmount = "whatever (integer value)"; // Get from database (e.g. from the field "curl_requests") or text file

    $newAmount = $currentAmount + 1;

    set_new_amount($username, $newAmount); // Update to database or text file

}

?>
```